# Reading new format in INI file perl

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, parameters, cgi

I have another problem regarding the INI file. My teacher had renewed the configuration of the files. Now my codes can't read this new configuration file. The format of it has been changed. How to read this format in the INI file in perl?

```
[section1]
value1
value2
```

As you can see, the format of the INI file now has only values in it. The parameter is gone. How can perl read this line? It does not have any **parameters** and only **values** are left. I want to read only the **values**. I use Config::Tiny before to read the line but i can't seem to solve this problem with this :

```
my $file = "file directory";

my $Config = Config::Tiny->read($file);
$Config->{"section1"}->{_};
```

Are my codes wrong? Because i can't get the output from this code. Can anybody help me fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: That is not a valid ini file.

Comment: Then it cant be read? or i have to use other method? @jaypal

Comment: Another method probably. All these modules (including `Config::Simple`, `Config::IniFiles` etc) are based on documented INI format.

Comment: Do you know any other those methods? I can't seem to solve this issue. I thought its still used the Config::Tiny @jaypal

Comment: Like @jaypal said you must use another method to read this file. I hope someone expert in this matter can help you.

Comment: i Hope so. I'm still waiting for an answer. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to deal with it yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.10.0;

sub read_not_ini
{
    my $file = shift;

    my %values;
    my $section;

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't read $file: $!";
    while (<$fh>)
    {
        # skip comments, blank lines.
        next if /^\s*#/ or /^\s*$/;

        # don't need/want end-line character.
        chomp;

        if (/^\[([^\]]+)\]/)
        {
            my $s = $1;
            $section = $values{$s} //= [];
        }
        elsif($section)
        {
            push @$section, $_;
        }
        else
        {
            say STDERR "$file: values without a section: line $.";
        }
    }
    return \%values;
}

my $Config = read_not_ini(shift); # pass in as param
say for @{$Config->{"section1"}};
```